# I'm trying to make a game but I ran into a problem

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a game in which your goal is to get to the end of a maze without hitting any walls, I want to make sure you can't stop moving. So when I press W I should move up and when I would press D I should stop moving up and start moving to the right.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make sure you stop moving when you press another key.

This is what I have now:

```
function moveRight() {
    var moveRight = setInterval(function(){
        let top =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
        let left =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left"));
        left += 1;
        character.style.left = left + "px";
    }, 1);
}
```

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    if(event.key==="a") {moveLeft();}
    if(event.key==="d") {moveRight();}

    if(event.key==="s") {moveDown();}
    if(event.key==="w") {moveUp();}
});
```

Comment: This previous answer of mine might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62617521/1913729

Comment: setInterval continues to fire? change `var moveRight = ` to `movement = ` and then in each call to move* funcs add a `clearInterval(movement)` before creating it again.

Comment: according to this code you will never stop moving. You need to remove those setIntervals before moving to the next direction.

Comment: a better way would be in keydown event set a variable as to which direction its moving, then you only need one setInterval, as it can simply then look at the current direction.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that's a nice way to get this done.
I still don't understand what it meant by `i want to make sure you can't stop moving`

Comment: heres a snake game example which you might find interesting: https://uztb7.csb.app/

Comment: in my game projects i usually assign 1 to W and D and -1 to S and A. if i then add them up for each axis, i get correct directions even if you press W and S together. fun fact, i you use the gamepad API, you'll get similar values for movement axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your character continues moving because you are setting the interval and never stopping it.
First you need all the references to your intervals as global variables, so define them outside function:

```
var movingRight = false;
var movingLeft = false;
var movingUp = false;
var movingDown = false;
```

Then you need event listeners for both keydown and keyup

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    if(event.key==="a") {startMoveLeft();}
    if(event.key==="d") {startMoveRight();}
    if(event.key==="s") {startMoveDown();}
    if(event.key==="w") {startMoveUp();}
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.key==="a") {stopMoveLeft();}
    if(event.key==="d") {stopMoveRight();}
    if(event.key==="s") {stopMoveDown();}
    if(event.key==="w") {stopMoveUp();}
});
```

Finally create all the start and stop functions, example for Right:

```
function startMoveRight() {
    movingRight = setInterval(function(){
        let top =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
        let left =
        parseInt (window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left"));
        left += 1;
        character.style.left = left + "px";
    }, 1);
}
function stopMoveRight() {
    clearInterval(movingRight);
}
```

Comment: This is the right approach - though the querent says that it shouldn't be possible to stop moving.  So there would be no need for `keyup` listeners; instead, each `startMoveX` method should clear all existing non-null intervals before starting a new one.